# Polynomial function with odd and even Exponents in c++

Tags: c++, polynomials, coefficients

I am new here and a beginner in programming.
For a small only private used project I want to calculate coefficients of various polynomial models. A kind of polyfit for a data set.

1. the normal polynomial model (x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3)
2. only with even exponents (x^0, x^2, x^4)
3. only odd exponents

I found a function on the following page where the normal polynomial model is applied (I did not write this code, the rights are not mine)

https://gist.github.com/chrisengelsma/108f7ab0a746323beaaf7d6634cf4add

but I would like to model this code to use the two other models.

My math skills are unfortunately limited.
If I see the right one, I only have to change the following lines or ?

original:

```
     // X = vector that stores values of sigma(xi^2n)
  std::vector<TYPE> X(tnp1);
  for (int i = 0; i < tnp1; ++i) {
    X[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
      X[i] += (TYPE)pow(x.get(j), i);
  }
```

The original for the normal polynomial.
The next for even

```
     // X = vector that stores values of sigma(xi^2n)
  std::vector<TYPE> X(tnp1);
  for (int i = 0; i < tnp1; i+2) {
    X[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
      X[i] += (TYPE)pow(x.get(j), i);
  }
```

and the next for odd

```
     // X = vector that stores values of sigma(xi^2n)
  std::vector<TYPE> X(tnp1);
  for (int i = 1; i < tnp1; i+2) {
    X[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
      X[i] += (TYPE)pow(x.get(j), i);
  }
```

The same for this snippet:

```
  // Y = vector to store values of sigma(xi^n * yi)
  std::vector<TYPE> Y(np1);
  for (int i = 0; i < np1; ++i) {
    Y[i] = (TYPE)0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      Y[i] += (TYPE)pow(x[j], i)*y[j];
    }
  }
```

I have no way of verifying the results. At least I don't know how.
Therefore I hope that someone can tell me that I have understood this correctly and can implement it.

Comment: "for even" and "for odd" are wrong: `i` won't be updated and the outer loop will be infinite.

Comment: i want to calculate the coefficients

Comment: maybe instead o changing the for loop , change the last line  X[i] += (TYPE)pow(x.get(j), i+1); or i+2

Comment: A "normal polynomial model" with every odd coefficient zero would only have "even exponents".    Similarly, a "normal polynomial model" with every even coefficient zero would have only "odd exponents".

Comment: does this not have to be taken into account when calculating the coefficients ?  When i get coefficient c1, c2, c3 ,c4 with the normal model and i want a polynomial with a odd order. i can't just let the even values leave out. Then the different models do not make sense

Comment: You can perfectly restrict the values of eligible exponents and directly apply the same least square methods. Just suppress some lines and columns of the matrix involved

Answer (score 0):

If your fitting function is linear with respect to the estimated coefficients, you can use the Linear Least Squares algorithm as a general approach. I will use [alglib](https://www.alglib.net/) for the examples, but any C++ math library should also do the job.

Your fitting function can be represented as

```
f(t) = c0 * f0(t) + c1 * f1(t) + c2 * f2(t) + ...
```

where (in your even-coefficients polynomial example) your fx can be

```
f0 = constant
f1 = t^2
f2 = t^4
```

Having that you can define the [Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) problem:

```
A * c - y  ---> min
```

where `A` is the matrix of your fitting f(t) curve values in different time points

```
A = [[f0(t0), f1(t0), f2(t0)],
  [f0(t1), f1(t1), f2(t1)]
  [f0(t2), f1(t2), f2(t2)],
          ...
  [f0(tn), f1(tn), f2(tn)]];
```

`c` is the vector of coefficients that you want to estimate, and `y` are the values that you measured (`y` and `t` are your inputs to the algorithm).

This problem can be solved with `alglib::lsfitlinear`:

```
    const size_t numPoints(1000);
    double p0(-1000);
    double p2(-5.5);
    double p4(1.1);
    std::vector<double> t(numPoints);
    std::generate(t.begin(), t.end(), [i = 0]() mutable { return 0.001*i++; });
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
    std::normal_distribution<> gauss{0, 0.5};  // let's apply some noise
    std::vector<double> y(numPoints);
    // generate fake data
    std::generate(y.begin(), y.end(), [i = 0, &t, &gauss, &gen, p0, p2, p4]() mutable {
        double result = p0 + p2*std::pow(t[i], 2) + p4*std::pow(t[i], 4);
        result += gauss(gen);
        i++;
        return result;
    });
    alglib::real_1d_array y_array;
    alglib::real_1d_array t_array;
    alglib::real_2d_array F_array;
    y_array.setcontent(y.size(), y.data());
    t_array.setcontent(t.size(), t.data());
    // LS array for 3 basis functions: f0 = 1, f1 = x^2, f2 = x^4
    F_array.setlength(numPoints, 3);
    std::normal_distribution<> gauss2{1, 1}; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        F_array(i, 0) = 1;
        F_array(i, 1) = std::pow(t[i], 2);
        F_array(i, 2) = std::pow(t[i], 4);
    }
    alglib::ae_int_t info;
    alglib::real_1d_array coeffs;
    alglib::lsfitreport rep;
    alglib::lsfitlinear(y_array, F_array, numPoints, 3, info, coeffs, rep);
    std::cout << "Success: " << info << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Results: " << coeffs(0) << ", " << coeffs(1) << ", " << coeffs(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RMS: " << rep.rmserror << std::endl;
```

However, this approach can become numerically unstable for big values. Try to set bigger time values and see that the result will be worse than alternative approach below. Note that your matrix is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), so it will become irreversible for time values being distributed on both sides of Y axis, because you use only even exponent coefficients. Example results:

```
Success: 1
Results: -1000.04, -5.45533, 1.19111
RMS: 0.479453
```

[image: Results of LeastSquares algorithm]

Fortunately, in this particular case (even polynomial coefficients) you can do the math trick, by substituting

```
tp <--- t^2
```

and reforming your problem as standard polynomial fitting with function

```
f(t) = C + t^2 + t^4 = c + tp + tp^2
```

and using `alglib::polynomialfit` with 2nd order polynomial (`m=3` in alglib):

```
    alglib::barycentricinterpolant p;
    alglib::polynomialfitreport rep2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        // substitution: new t is equal to old t^2
        t_array(i) = std::pow(t_array(i), 2);
    }
    alglib::polynomialfit(t_array, y_array, 3, info, p, rep2);
    alglib::real_1d_array powerCoeffs;
    alglib::polynomialbar2pow(p, powerCoeffs);
    std::cout << "Success: " << info << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Results: " << powerCoeffs(0) << ", " << powerCoeffs(1) << ", " << powerCoeffs(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RMS: " << rep2.rmserror << std::endl;
```

Example results (in this conditions they are the same, but in general this algorithm behaves better):

```
Success: 1
Results: -1000.04, -5.45533, 1.19111
RMS: 0.479453
```

`alglib::polynomialfit` is nice, because it uses barycentric interpolants, which is more stable numerically.